# Rules for 2NF Normalization

Tags: normalization

I am struggling with the concept of 2NF form. Lets say I have a set of functional dependencies for  `R1(A,B,C,D,E,H,M,K)` Where :

```
B  -> M,C
AB -> D
DH -> E
H  -> K
A  -> H
```

Whenever I try to decompose it, I directly get 3 NF 3NF tables. What are the rules to get something in  2NF, with minimal set of tables ?

Now how do I take this further to  3NF or BCNF?

Answer (score 0):

I would love to just add a comment here, but I have not the reputation. I struggled with 2NF as well, leaping straight from 1NF to 3NF. Here's how I learned the normal forms for things:

1NF: The key.

All attributes depend on the primary key. (as simply as you can take it)

2NF: The whole key

All attributes depend on the entire primary key. This is where you would have a composite key for all attributes, but still only one table.

3NF: Nothing but the key.

All attributes depend on they primary key, and the primary key only. This results in multiple tables.

For 2NF, your primary key would be a composite of A, B, D, H (I believe)

Hope this helps